# How can I query mongodb for a list of credit cards that are about to expire?

Tags: mongodb, date, meteor, momentjs

My collection has documents with card as a subdocument array holding each card. Each card is an object with many keys. The two keys for expiration are expiration_month and expiration_year.

Here is an example.

```
{
    _id: '1',
    card: [
        {
            'expiration_month': 10,
            'expiration_year': 2017
        },
        {
            'expiration_month': 01,
            'expiration_year': 2015
        },
    ]
}
```

How would I publish the right list to the subscription for this route so that I can use an each loop to get the right list? I just want to get any cards that expire in the next three months.

```
{{#each expiring_cards}}
    {{> ExpiringCards}}
{{/each}}   

Meteor.publish('card_expiring', function () {
    var before_date = moment(new Date()).add(3, 'month');
    return Donate.find( { moment(new Date('card[0].expiration_year' + '/' + 'card[0].expiration_month'))._d : { $lte: before_date} });
});
```

I know the above code for publish doesn't work, how could I change it to make it work, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why the details are stored in the database as string with separate values for month and year? As opposed to Number for each, or even single date objects?

Comment: Good point, that is just how I get it when the card is tokenized, but if it make the answer easier I can combine the month and year.

Comment: Ok, yea I see that would pretty much solve it

Comment: Well if you can change the schema, I would recommend it. Will not only make it easier but also improve performance, because what you are asking for is a complex query on multiple fields.

Comment: Yea, now I just need to find out how to update the existing records with a date object that is composed of exipiration_year and expiration_month ... hmmm

Comment: When you store numbers as Strings, it becomes impossible to compare them with numbers. Store them as Numbers. Since you have asked a solution for this, you would get one, where the calculation of the expiry date needs to be done on the application server/client side.

Comment: @BatScream Curious why you would say , "impossible". Javascript doesn't even make it hard let alone impossible... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: @JoshOne Yes you are correct. By impossible i meant its not possible to pass a document field as a parameter to javascript function in the aggregation pipeline and get it executed in the server side.In this case the `parseInt()` method.

Comment: I don't want to be a jerk but: How can you be PCI compliance with nodejs? Do you see a problem in using a recent, non field-tested technology to do such a critical like online payments? Why storing credit when you have things like BrainTree that are easy to integrate and don't ask for PCI Compliance?

Comment: @Mário I'm using balanced payments and I don't have to worry about pci compliance because I tokenize their card client side using balanced.js so I never even see their card information, just what balanced sends back to me.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way seems to be to join these two fields into a Date object, then run the below query.

[How to combine the two fields - answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27071226/582309)

```
Meteor.publish('card_expiring', function () {
    var today = new Date();
    var future_date = new Date(new Date(today).setMonth(today.getMonth()+3));
    return Donate.find({'card.expires' : {$lte : future_date }}, { card : true } );
});
```

Of course this just gets me any card subdocument that matches this query, which means that would include the cards that don't match, but that are in a subdocument that does.

To filter even further I used this in my helper.

```
Template.ListExpiringCards.helpers({
    list: function () {    
    //The subscription filters out the records with subdocument card, 
    //which contain cards expiring in the next 3 months
        return Donate.find(); 
    },
    expiring_cards: function () {
    //This further filters only to the cards that match the above criteria
    // then returns an array to the Meteor template for the each loop
        var returnThisValue = [];
        this.card.forEach(function(entry) {
            var today = new Date();
            var future_date = new Date(new Date(today).setMonth(today.getMonth()+3));
            if (entry.expires <= future_date) {
                returnThisValue.push(entry);
            }
        });
        return returnThisValue;
    }
});
```

And this in my template

```
{{#each list}}
    {{#each expiring_cards}}
        {{> ExpiringCards}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```