# How can two keys be combined into one new object in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Here is a sample of my document.

```
{
    _id: '1',
    card: [
        {
            'expiration_month': '10',
            'expiration_year': '2017'
        },
        {
            'expiration_month': '01',
            'expiration_year': '2015'
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to combine the month and year into a date object and store it in the same object these keys are already stored in.

So it would look like this where `expires` would actually be a date object.

```
{
    _id: '1',
    card: [
        {
            'expiration_month': '10',
            'expiration_year': '2017',
            expires: {                
            }
        },
        {
            'expiration_month': '01',
            'expiration_year': '2015',
            expires: {                
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried this, but I know it is wrong.

`db.collection.update({'card.expires': {$exists: false}}, { $set: moment(new Date(card.expiration_year + '-' + card.expiration_month)) })`

Comment: We cannot construct a vaild Date object without a `month`, a `year` and a `date`.

Comment: Ok, I was actually using momentjs, but I removed that from the example because I didn't want to complicate the problem. Looks like it had the reverse effect. I put it back in my example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
db.yourcollection.find().snapshot().forEach(
  function (e) {
    var saveChanges = false;

    if(e.cards && e.cards.length > 0){
        for(var i=0; i < e.cards.length; i++){
            if(e.cards[i].expiration_month && e.cards[i].expiration_year){
                e.cards[i].expires = new Date(e.cards[i].expiration_year, e.cards[i].expiration_month, 1);

                saveChanges = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(saveChanges) db.yourcollection.save(e);
  }
)
```

Comment: This works, except that ```new Date(e.cards[i].expiration_year, e.cards[i].expiration_month, 1);``` actually returns what seems to be the wrong date. for expiration_year = 2015 and expiration_month = 12 it returns ```2016-01-01 06:00:00.000Z```

Comment: in that case just google around a bit on how to handle this type of conversions on JS dates, now that you have the values and can save them it will be a lot easier

Comment: Thanks, seems easy enough to resolve. Turns out the date just looks this way in Mongo, but once I query for it I get the right date back. Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly mongodb doesn't allow updates based off of fields in the document. 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458

You'll need to do this as two separate operations, one that finds documents to modify, and one that updates those documents with the correct new date.

Comment: Ok, could I do a find, then iterate over the cursor and update that way?

Answer (score 0):

One way of updating the `card` array elements would be:

```
db.collection.find({"card.expires":{$exists:false}}).forEach(function(doc){
var cards = doc.card.map(function(card){
var date = new ISODate(card.expiration_year+card.expiration_month+"01");
if(!card.hasOwnProperty("expires")){card["expires"]=date;}
return card;
})
db.collection.update({"_id":doc._id},{"card":cards});
});
```